# VBA_Web Scrape - Next Page

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

Login Issue [ Done ];
Table Data Scrape [ Done ]

I am currently stuck at how to

1. count no. pages to repeat data scrape. [ Solve ]

   For Each HTMLTable In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("li")(0)
   With ActiveSheet
   .Range("A" & i).Value = HTMLTable.Children(0).textContent
2. go to next page

I have posted the picture of the HTML code of that website & its interface.
I wish to

1. Get all the page no. from IE to Excel so that excel knows how many loop it has to perform Data scrape & goto next page
2. Or, if it is possible, count pages and repeat loop.

I am not really familiar with IE. especially identifying Class/ID/Tag within html code.
The below script is my current code.

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal HWND As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Sub Test()
Dim i As Long
Dim URL As String
Dim IE, ObjElement, ObjCollection As Object


Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

IE.Visible = True

URL = "xxxxx"

IE.Navigate URL

Application.StatusBar = URL & " is loading. Please wait..."

Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

Application.StatusBar = URL & " Loaded"

'---------------------------------------------------

Dim HWNDsrc

HWNDsrc = IE.HWND
SetForegroundWindow HWNDsrc


Dim n As Long

                    For n = 0 To IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input").Length - 1
                     With IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")(n)
                        
                        Select Case (.Name)
                            Case "UserName"
                                .Value = "ABC"
                                
                            Case "Password"
                                .Value = "12345"
                                
                            Case "btn.btn-default"
                                .Click
                                n = 99999
                                
                            Case Else
                                    'ignore
                            
                            End Select
                            End With
                        Next n
On Error Resume Next
IE.Document.forms(0).submit
    
Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
            
   URL = "xxxxx"

IE.Navigate URL
            
   

Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

                    For n = 0 To IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input").Length - 1
                     With IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")(n)
                        
                        
                         Select Case (.Name)
                        
                        
                            Case "LookupModel.StartDate"
                                .Value = "06/30/2022"
                        
                            Case "LookupModel.EndDate"
                                .Value = "08/01/2022"
                        
                
                            Case "LookupModel.Station"
                                .Value = "ICN"
                        
                            Case "LookupModel.IsInbound"
                                .Value = "False"
                                .Click
                                n = 99999
                            Case Else
                                    'ignore
                            
                            End Select
                            End With
                        Next n
                        
Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
                        
IE.Document.forms(0).submit

Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

Dim HTMLTable As IHTMLElement


    For Each HTMLTable In IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
        With ActiveSheet
            .Range("A" & i).Value = HTMLTable.Children(0).textContent
            .Range("B" & i).Value = HTMLTable.Children(1).textContent
            .Range("C" & i).Value = HTMLTable.Children(2).textContent
            .Range("D" & i).Value = HTMLTable.Children(3).textContent
            .Range("E" & i).Value = HTMLTable.Children(4).textContent
            .Range("F" & i).Value = HTMLTable.Children(5).textContent
            .Range("G" & i).Value = HTMLTable.Children(6).textContent
            
            .Range("H" & i).Value = HTMLTable.Children(7).textContent
            .Range("I" & i).Value = HTMLTable.Children(8).textContent
            .Range("J" & i).Value = HTMLTable.Children(9).textContent
            i = i + 1
        End With
    Next HTMLTable




End Sub
```

[image: IE- Code]

[image: IE - Interface]

Comment: Maybe I'm being too simplistic here but.. why do you need to know how many pages there are? Why not just keep cycling through the pages using [Next page] button until the [Next page] is no longer present or is disabled?

Comment: Good idea, but either do i know how to pick up that button.

However, i  have just use a stupid method. " I count the page, and change URL of that page " and simply navigate URL.

it is not something i want to learn. but it is currently a CAN DO method.

Comment: What about getting the number of `<li>` in `<ul class="pagination">`. After that you can get the inner text of *number-1* `<li>`, that's the total number of pages. Then you can count from 1 to that inner text number to get all page numbers.

Comment: That is what i am doing.

i get the entire li  and using MAX function to get the final page no.

now i am looking if any better idea

Comment: I haven't come up with other methods. Let's see if other community members have other suggestions.